# Как собрать полную коллекцию для меню? laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет!
Заранее всем благодарен!

Пробую собрать обратное меню на ларе. Чет не получается!
Ко мне приходят последние подкатегории (коллекция), например (выделил жирным):
одежда-женская-**джинсы**
одежда-женская-**брюки**
одежда-мужская-повседневная-**джинсы**
одежда-мужская-повседневная-**брюки**

**Необходимо получить полную коллекцию всех дочерних категорий!**
пробую так:

```
function catNet($categories, $array = null){
    if($array == null){
        $array = collect();
        foreach ($categories as $category){
            if($category->parent AND !$categories->firstWhere('id', $category->parent->id)){
                $categories = $categories->add($category->parent);
                $array = $array->add($category->parent);
            }
        }
        return catNet($categories,$array);
    }elseif(!$array->isEmpty()){
        foreach ($array as $category){
            if($category->parent AND !$categories->firstWhere('id', $category->parent->id)){
                $categories->add($category->parent);
                $array->add($category->parent);
            }
        }
        return catNet($categories,$array);
    }else{
        return $categories;
    }

}

$res = catNet($categories);
dd($res);
```

Если есть возможность подскажите пжл как собрать но с фунциями замыкания (для себя):
пробую так тоже не выходит

```
$result2 = function ($item) use ($categories){
    if($item->parent && !$categories->firstWhere('id', $item->parent->id)){
        $categories->add($item->parent);
    }
};
$categories->each(function ($item) use ($result2){
    $result2($item);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result2 = function ($item) use ($categories){
    while($item->parent_id !== 0 && !$categories->firstWhere('id', $item->parent_id)){
        $categories->add($item->parent);
            $item = $item->parent;
        }
};

$categories->each(function ($item) use ($result2){
    $result2($item);
});
```